# USB3.0 PD port ORing

Tags: power, usb-pd, power-delivery

I was designing a product in which two USB Power Delivery ports are populated in the design so as to:

- Provide power from wall charger supporting PD
- Provide high speed communication with laptop

Now we are thinking of using this second port also with PD functionality, so it can consume power from laptop supporting PD in case power through PD port-1 is absent.
But this requires ORing circuit for these two USB PD ports.

So, does any one have any knowledge on ORing two USB PD ports or any such designs proven to be successful?

Comment: Your question needs more details, chip used, circuit... PD is negotiated over the bus, so you may want to enable only one at a time if both are connected? What is the concern over the ORing?

Comment: The concern is that since we are using PD over USB, there is not Proper ORing circuit for selecting between these sources. we are using STUSB4500 for PD sink Controller for both the PD ports.